# Indecipherable Data on Serial Monitor

Tags: microcontroller, serial, embedded, uart, wifi

I have ready made working electronic product. I am applying reverse engineering on it. The WiFi module is connected to micro-controller via UART( RX & TX). The android app sends command to WiFi and micro-controller works as per the command. I have attached a USB to TTL cable on RX and TX also command ground as well of WiFi module. The cable is connected to serial monitor on PC. When the app send data to WiFi, the serial monitor shows Indecipherable value. I have checked every baud rate possible. Instead of USB to TTL cable, I also used HC05 Bluetooth module. But it shows Indecipherable data. How can I get the readable values on my serial monitor. Do i need to disconnect micro controller from WiFi?

No RS232 is used in whole design.

The first two images has similar data but with different baud rate. First image data is set at 4800 and second one at 9600 with No parity, 8 bit data, stop bit 1. "0D" is just enter command( For readability).

[image]
[image]

Comment: The "garbage" might be binary-encoded data. There's no particular reason to think that the protocol might be directly human-readable. Indeed, many "app + gadget" applications do most of the software heavy lifting (including all of the UI) in the app, and send very simple commands to the gadget.

Comment: You expect its designers to have made reverse engineering easy for you?

Comment: By garbage value, do you mean that the same stimulus does not yield the same value? Otherwise, if the values are predictable, how are they garbage?

Comment: @DaveTweed Is there any possible solution for this? What are the factors that I need to check?

Comment: Use a 'scope to determine the actual bit rate, and then dump the data to a file and try analyzing the data for patterns using a hex editor. See whether the data correlates in any way with your actions in the UI.

Comment: @Jacob The same function on app, does send same value, but if I can't understand it or can't read it, it is garbage value for me.

Comment: @DaveTweed Sure, will do that as well.

Comment: @AnujMattóõ In that case I would have a look at the datasheet or other documentation for the WiFi module. I would guess that you're seeing a data package and that it should be possible to identify the beginning and end, and thereby the data (which will probably still make no sense to you). Maybe you could identify some standard messages from the WiFi module. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Machines talk in binary, humans can't read it. This does not mean that all binary is garbage. You have to carefully analyze the packets. Since you can get repeated values for a specific action try checking two actions against each other. What changes and what stays the same. It's up to you to find the pattern that makes sense.

Comment: @Jacob This is the link to WiFi Module page [link] (http://www.hi-flying.com/products_detail/&productId=39&comp_stats=comp-FrontProducts_list01-111.html).

Comment: @AnujMattóõ What I meant was that in your place I would study it, not that I would do it for you 

Comment: @Jacob Yes, of course. I have to do that. Just help me. I couldn't attach the datasheet. So had to attach the link. My only need is to know what commands or data the application is sending to microcontroller. That's it. It will help in designing the product.

Comment: Post samples of the "garbage" labeling them with the commands they represent. A diagram of your setup would be much more helpful than all the text. There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar. Post links to datasheets in your question and not sprinkled through the comments. Change the word "garbage" in the title and post to "un-decipherable" if that's what you mean.

Comment: Now hit the "Show Hex" button and copy'n'paste the results into your post so we can see what the "." characters are. This code looks fairly trivial.

Comment: @transistor Unable to Decipher what "." means. It occurs in every command. I have paste the HEX code as well.

Comment: @Jacob Did find anything about the WiFi module?

Comment: @DaveTweed I have attached the screenshot of the data which I was getting on Serial Monitor. Please have a look.

Comment: The default baud rate for the WiFi module is 115200. Have you tried that?

Comment: @TomCarpenter Yes, I have tried that as well. The serial monitor just show "." character repeatedly in sequence.

Answer (score 5):

The first hex screengrab (at 4800 baud) looks promising:

What you are seeing is a 4-byte message. The message is not in [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/)  so it's not human readable. The message is coded in binary (or hexadecimal, if you prefer) and so we need to view and interpret it in that way. Binary typically results in shorter messages than ASCII.

[image]

*Figure 1. The ASCII table may help in some cases. 'OD', which appears in your screengrabs, is the 'CR' (carriage return) character.*

- Each line starts with ASCII character 'q' (0h71). It's probably a preamble.
- The second character in the responses you have posted is ASCII '$' (0h23) or '#' (0h24).
- The third character is fixed as 0h0F.
- The fourth character appears to be a checksum. You can confirm this using your computer's calculator in *Programmer* mode. Select 'byte' data type (to truncate to 8-bits):

  - 0h71 + 0h24 + 0h0F = 0hA4.
  - 0h71 + 0h23 + 0h0F = 0hA3.

You haven't given any information what you did to generate the *$* and *#* symbols so I can't help any further at this time.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like 4800 bps is the correct speed. The 9600 data is obviously (!) the same data sampled twice as often. Here is how you do that analysis:

Here's the 9600 baud data as it would appear as a bit sequence. The data is written LSB first, and I've represented the start and stop bits as lower-case `o` (zero) and `i` (one), respectively.

```
|06      ||3F      ||60      ||0C      ||FE      ||80      ||60      ||CC      |
o01100000io11111100io00000110io00110000io01111111io00000001io00000110io00110011i
```

Here's the 4800 baud data, stretched out to the same time scale:

```
| 71               | | 24              || 0F              | | A4               |
o 1 0 0 0  1 1 1 0 io 0 0 1 0  0 1 0 0 io 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 i o 0 0 1 0  0 1 0 1 i
```

Note that each bit in the lower stream corresponds to two bits of the same value in the upper stream. Keep in mind that when running at 9600, your wiretap is resynchronizing on a high-to-low transition, so there's a little bit of "slop" around the byte boundaries at that speed.

It's also clear that an even slower speed would NOT be correct — there are single isolated ones and zeros in the data at 4800, which means that this is the minimum sampling rate for this data.